# $@ except the 1st argument

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need to write a shell script that runs in this way:

```
./myscript arg1 arg2_1 arg2_2 arg2_3 ....... arg2_#
```

there is a for loop inside script

```
for i in $@
```

However, as I know, $@ includes $1 up to $($#-1). But for my program $1 is distinctly different from $2 $3 $4 etc. I would like to loop from $2 to the end... How do i achieve this? Thank you:)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

First, note that `$@` without quotes makes no sense and should not be used. `$@` should only be used quoted (`"$@"`) and in list contexts.

`for i in "$@"` qualifies as a list context, but here, to loop over the positional parameters, the canonical, most portable and simpler form is:

```
for i
do something with "$i"
done
```

Now, to loop over the elements starting from the second one, the canonical and most portable way is to use `shift`:

```
first_arg=$1
shift # short for shift 1
for i
do something with "$i"
done
```

After `shift`, what used to be `$1` has been removed from the list (but we've saved it in `$first_arg`) and what used to be in `$2` is now in `$1`. The positional parameters have been *shifted* `1` position to the left (use `shift 2` to shift by 2...). So basically, our loop is looping from what used to be the second argument to the last.

With `bash` (and `zsh` and `ksh93`, but that's it), an alternative is to do:

```
for i in "${@:2}"
do something with "$i"
done
```

But note that it's not standard `sh` syntax so should not be used in a script that starts with `#! /bin/sh -`.

In `zsh` or `yash`, you can also do:

```
for i in "${@[3,-3]}"
do something with "$i"
done
```

to loop from the 3rd to the 3rd last argument.

In `zsh`, `$@` is also known as the `$argv` array. So to pop elements from the beginning or end of the arrays, you can also do:

```
argv[1,3]=() # remove the first 3 elements
argv[-3,-1]=()
```

(`shift` can also be written `1=()` in `zsh`)

In `bash`, you can only assign to the `$@` elements with the `set` builtin, so to pop 3 elements off the end, that would be something like:

```
set -- "${@:1:$#-3}"
```

And to loop from the 3rd to the 3rd last:

```
for i in "${@:3:$#-5}"
do something with "$i"
done
```

POSIXly, to pop the last 3 elements of `"$@"`, you'd need to use a loop:

```
n=$(($# - 3))
for arg do
  [ "$n" -gt 0 ] && set -- "$@" "$arg"
  shift
  n=$((n - 1))
done
```

Comment: An alternate (and ugly) bash possibility: indirect variables: `for ((i=2; i<=$#; i++)); do something with "${!i}"; done`

Comment: I am more familiar with this version, since I am more familiar with c++ :)

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - could you please explain why `$@` without quotes makes no sense and should not be used?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - because `"$@"` means quote every string in `$*`, so for `cmd "a = b" c d`, inside `cmd`, `"$@"` would have three elements, `a = b`, `b`, and `c`, whereas `$@` would be no different than `$*`, producing 5 elements: `a`, `=`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Answer (score 19):

I think you want the `shift` builtin. It renames `$2` to `$1`, `$3` to `$2`, etc.

Like this:

```
shift
for i in "$@"; do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: could you explain in more detail how do I achieve that in the for loop? Thank you.

Comment: You don't - you use it before entering the `for` loop, then you just loop through $@ normally. After the `shift` call, $@ should be `arg2_1 arg2_2 arg2_3...`

Comment: However, I will have one more question: Suppose I want to loop from $1 until  $($#-2) (i.e. arg_1 until arg_2_#-1, except arg_2_#)... What should I do?

Comment: @user40780 - that is answered in the selected answer.  Instead of using `shift`, use `"${@:1:$#-2}"` .  To understand better why this works, study "bash arrays", and note that $@ is a special case.  Where you'd use `${A[@]:1:$#-2}` for an array named `A`, for `$@` you omit the `[@]` part.

Answer (score 4):

There's always the caveman approach:

```
first=1
for i
do
        if [ "$first" ]
        then
                first=
                continue
        fi
        something with "$i"
done
```

This leaves `$@` intact (in case you want to use it later),
and simply loops over every argument, but doesn't process the first one.

Answer (score 3):

In bash you can also write that loop with explicit indexing:

```
for ((i=2; i<=$#; ++i)); do
  process "${!i}"
done
```

This iterates over all arguments from the second one to the last one. If you want to exclude the last argument instead, simply make this

```
for ((i=1; i<=$#-1; ++i)); do
  process "${!i}"
done
```

and if you only want to take every other argument, write it as

```
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i+=2)); do
  process "${!i}"
done
```

The story behind this is the [arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic) version of the [`for` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#index-for), combined with the [argument-count `$#`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0023) and the [variable indirection `${…}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

One nice application is that you can use this to decide, inside the loop, whether a given option will take the argument which follows it as a value. If it does, increment `i` (e.g. writing `: $((++i))`) to consume the next value and skip it during iteration.