# Splitting parameter list

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

I want to create a bash function that will accept variable number of parameters. There must be at least one parameter. Then I call another program and need to insert fixed values between the first parameter accepted and the rest of parameters.

I do it based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225943/except-the-1st-argument)

```
tt() {
  name="$1"
  params="${@:2}"
  someapp ${name} 1234 /some/path "${params}"
}
```

But it doesn't work as intended as if I call it

```
tt John has fun
```

the resulting call will be

```
someapp John 1234 /some/path 'has fun'
```

note quotes, while I need the result to be

```
someapp John 1234 /some/path has fun
```

with two last args not in common quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick out the first argument, `shift`, then call your other command with the saved 1st argument, and the remaining ones:

```bash
tt () {
   name=$1
   shift

   someapp "$name" 1234 /some/path "$@"
}
```

Alternatively, with a named array like what you attempted:

```bash
tt () {
    name=$1
    params=( "${@:2}" )

    someapp "$name" 1234 /some/path "${params[@]}"
}
```

The main issue with your own code is that you are not creating or using the `params` variable as an array.  Doing that correctly would look like `params=( "${@:2}" )` followed by using at as `"${params[@]}"`, including the double quotes and the `[@]` bit.

Array assignments always look like `name=( ... )`, so what you get with `params="${@:2}"` is not an array but a single string consisting of the 2rd element onward from `"$@"`, concatenated with spaces as delimiters.

Without the double quotes in `"${params[@]}"`, the shell would split each element of the array on spaces, tabs, and newlines (the characters in `$IFS` by default), and then apply filename globbing on each generated word.  Without `[@]`, you only get the first element of the array.

---

A minimalistic rewrite:

```bash
tt () { someapp "$1" 1234 /some/path "${@:2}"; }
```

Comment: I'm using the first snippet with $@ (note: no quotes) as I read that "$@" and $@ produce different results in case arguments contain spaces. Is my understanding and use correct?

Comment: @IvanOnyshchenko `$@` should _always_ be quoted! Without quotes, the shell would split the strings in the argument list up into more strings on spaces, tabs, and newlines and perform filename globbing on those new strings.  This essentially stops you from passing arguments containing spaces (or at least doing it correctly, preserving the spaces).  Please also read  the answers to [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571)